# SQL Server Conditional Join between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have tables `A` and `B`, and I want to create a single select query with a conditional join like this

```
@customParam bit,

when customParam is true 
select * from A a join B b on a.B_Id = b.Id 
else
select * from A a join B b on b.someid = a.someid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF ELSE`:

```
IF @customParam = 1
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.B_Id = b.Id 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM A a JOIN  B b ON b.someid=a.someid
END
```

In one statement (poor performance):

```
SELECT * 
FROM A a 
JOIN B b 
  ON (@customParam = 1 AND a.B_Id = b.Id)
  OR (@customParam = 0 AND b.someid=a.someid)
```

You can also use Dynamic-SQL and build custom query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'SELECT * 
    FROM A a 
    JOIN B b
      ON <placeholder>';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<placeholder>',
                   CASE WHEN @customParam = 1 THEN 'a.B_Id = b.Id'                 
                        ELSE 'b.someid=a.someid'
                   END);    


EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @sql;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379027)**</kbd>

Comment: is there any way to do it with single select ? because i have complex query with multiple joins

Comment: this is the only way to have query with functionality i described ?
i mean is there any way with better performance?

Comment: @AndrejKovalksy You can build query with dynamic sql

Answer (score 2):

This could be achievable using [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Please see this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A AS a
INNER JOIN B AS b
    ON CASE
        WHEN @customParam = 1 AND b.Id = a.B_Id THEN 1
        WHEN @customParam = 0 AND b.someid = a.someid THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1;
```

Your query will check your `@customParam` value and based on that will compare your JOIN condition and if's a match - it will result in 1, which then compares to 1 (`END = 1;`) and it returns you result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query using `left join`.  However, you can't really use `*` to get the columns.  You need to use `coalesce()` (or similar functionality) to your original query:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.col1, b2.col1) as col1, . . ..
from A a left join
     B b1
     on b1.B_Id = a.Id and customParam is true left join
     B b2
     on b2.someid = a.someid and customerParam is not true
```

This can make use of indexes on "id" and "someid".

Answer (score 1):

are ID int?
not the best way but another way

```
declare @customParam bit;
set @customParam = 1;
select * from A  
join B  
on @customParam * A.B_Id + abs(@customParam-1) * A.someid 
 = @customParam * B.Id   + abs(@customParam-1) * B.someid;
```